# Questions on z3-solver simplification

Tags: z3py

I recently am trying out z3-solver to simplify expressions and have some questions about it.

According to my understanding, function `simplify()` and two other tactics including `ctx-simplify` and `ctx-solver-simplify` can be used to simplify an expression (https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/programming/Example%20Programs/Formula%20Simplification/)
For example, given e = `Or(x >= 3, x >= 5)` where `x` is Int.

- `simplify(e)` returns `Or(x >= 3, x >= 5)`
- `Tactic('ctx-simplify').apply(e)`  returns `Or(x >= 3, x >= 5)`
- `Tactic('ctx-solver-simplify').apply(e)`  returns `Or(x >= 3, x >= 5)`

Since my expected result is `x >= 3`, I have the following questions:

1. Are there any better built-in functions ?
2. If there is no better built-in function, how to achieve the result: x >= 3 ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045586/1911064) related post answer your question?

Comment: Yes, my problem is related to the one you suggested. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Z3 Boolean Expression Simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022373/z3-boolean-expression-simplification)